# ElasticSearch exclude result from being filtered where a condition is met

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to exclude some results from being filtered by geo_distance where a condition is met.

For example, I filter my results on geo distance but I want to include all results where status is abnormal and meets the match_phrase query (even if it is outside the geo_distance)

```
        GET /drive/_search
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "keywords": "wheels"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "name": "car sale"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "status": "normal"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "0.09km",
                    "address.coordinate": {
                      "lat": -33.703082,
                      "lon": 18.981069
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

I've been reading the documentation and googling, but I think I might be going in the wrong direction.

If you can point me in the right direction, or explain to me what a better solution could be to do this Id be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) :

> should
>
> The clause (query) should appear in the matching document. If the bool
>   query is in a query context and has a must or filter clause then a
>   document will match the bool query even if none of the should queries
>   match. In this case these clauses are only used to influence the
>   score. If the bool query is in a filter context or has neither must or
>   filter then at least one of the should queries must match a document
>   for it to match the bool query. This behavior may be explicitly
>   controlled by setting the minimum_should_match parameter.

So in your case the geo condition is in "***should***" since it can be optional and the rest in "***filter***" which are mandatory : the status and match_phrase

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "normal"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "car sale"
          }
        },

        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "keywords": "wheels"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "0.09km",
            "address.coordinate": {
              "lat": -33.703082,
              "lon": 18.981069
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```